# How can I add my existing SourceForge project files to a SourceForge repo?

Tags: git, svn, sourceforge

I have had a project on SourceForge for a while, and I just added a (SVN) repo to the project. However, the project files are not in the repo. How can I get the existing project files into the repository? Do I really have to download the entire project just to upload it into the repo with an SVN client? Can't I just point the repo to the existing folders in some way? Would a different repo type (e.g. Git) allow this?

Answer (score 0):

git certainly allows that. If you have a local repository and a new empty remote one you just do

```
git remote add sf $USER@git.code.sf.net:/p/$REPO # Get the correct URL from SF
git push -u sf master
```

Comment: All my code is in the SourceForge project. I don't have a local repo. Is there a way to put the code from the SF project directly into the SF repo without creating a local one?

Comment: I don't understand. In what form do you have files at SF? Just files? Not even in SVN? I doubt SF can convert them to SVN or git.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The files are "bare" uploads and are not currently in any repo.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options -- very simple one and a bit more complicated one. The simple one will help you copy your project's files without revision history. More complicated one will copy all repository revisions (i.e. you will copy the history of changes, not only the latest state).

**Without revision history: Copy your project's contents without revision history**

If you do not need to move all the revision history, you can simply run [`svn export URL-TO-CURRENT-PROJECT-TRUNK LOCAL-PATH`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) to get all the files from your project's trunk and then run [`svn import URL-TO-NEW-PROJECT-TRUNK LOCAL-PATH`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) to import the files to the new project. Read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Getting Data into Your Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html)

**With revision history: Replicate repository data with revision history**

You should be able to run [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to copy the repository data from one repo to another via HTTP(S) or svn:// URL. This will move all the revision history, not just plain files.

Note that some adjustments will be required on the side of the target repository to allow you use `svnsync`. You will be required to setup [pre-revprop-change](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) hook script on the target repository. It seems that [SourceForge allows you to setup the hook via direct ssh access](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/svn/#hooks). Read the documentation:

- [SVNBook | Replication with `svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication.svnsync)

Comment: I do not currently have the files in any repo. Are you saying that I need to download my files to my local system, create a local repo, and then push/sync that to the SF repo? I wanted to avoid the first two steps if possible.

Comment: @JedSchaaf if you don't have any working copy and don't have any repository, you can just follow the instructions from this doc http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html

Comment: Please forgive me for being obtuse, but to be clear, do I have to install a repo client to my system and use that? There's no way to just directly move or copy the files otherwise?

Comment: @JedSchaaf I do not understand what "repo client" is. I'm talking about any SVN client. It can be TortoiseSVN or cmd.exe command-line client. Anything that you prefer. Just take your project's data and import it to the repository.

Comment: That's what I meant - a client for working with a given type of repository, be it SVN, Git, Mercurial, or whatever. Am I required to have such a client in order to put the files into the repository? Is there no way to copy or move the files directly from the plain SF file listing to the SVN repository I added to the SF project without using an SVN client? (replace SVN with Git or hg as applicable)

Comment: @JedSchaaf oh, I got it. Sorry, I don't know whether SF supports uploads via the web browser. I guess that it does, but I'm not sure about that. If you plan to use version control, you must learn how to use the vcs client. Maybe we'll get a client that works like File Explorer in Windows in future. But that's my fantasy now.

Comment: The files are already uploaded to SF. I just wanted to move them directly into a repository without having to download them, add them to a local checkout of the repo, and then push the updates (re-uploading them).